# Greenbone-openvas container image failed to run in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr, openvas

I tried deploying a container image to aws ecs. I pushed the official image to ECR, created a task, but after running the task exited automatically with an exit code of 0. I also didn’t find logs to debug the issue.

Can anyone help me to solve the problem, please?

Thank you!

The image was pulled from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/greenbone/openvas-scanner)
Then I performed the following steps:

1. Tag the Docker image and push it to AWS ECR
2. Create a Fargate cluster for ECS
3. Create an ECS task definition for Greenbone OpenVAS
4. Run the ECS task

Comment: What happens if you run the same docker image locally, using the same environment variables and `ENTRYPOINT` and other settings that you are using in ECS?